# Retrieve contents/page names of various pages for use in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I'm trying to design a plugin that retrieves the contents of user selected pages and copy the contents into a giant single page. (As long single page websites are trendy right now)

These are the following functions I need to either find or build:

- Get list of page names in database.
- Get contents of the page with page name as the argument.

The pages I am talking about are the user edited pages in the `pages` section of the WordPress.

I'm hoping functions such as these are already apart of WordPress.

I did search [WordPress Dev](https://developer.wordpress.org) however I couldn't find anything appropriate.

EDIT:
I found `get_page()` however the function is now deprecated with the recommendation to use `get_post()`. However does this still work for pages? I thought that a page and post were logically separate entities, for example a different page and post could both share the same ID. Or am I wrong about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- [`get_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages); or
- [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts); or
- [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

to get a list of pages. They differ somewhat in details, so read up on that. But generally all of them should suffice, for you to achieve your goal. Just choose the best fitting one for your purpose.

For getting pages by name or better `title` you can use:

- [`get_page_by_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

Or use:

- [`get_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

if you decide to use the `ID` or the post object.

To save the user selection you probably want to make use of the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).